# Increase Apple Logo Brightness with Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, graphical-logo

Do any one of you know how to increase the brightness of the apple logo in cooca? I think it would be cool if my app could control that. Although you could increase the brightness of your screen that is not what I want, but what I want is just to increase the apple logo.

Best Regards,

Kevin

Comment: This question makes me hungry. Too many food references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't be done - see https://superuser.com/questions/37411/how-do-i-change-the-external-apple-logo-to-any-other-color-by-going-through-termi

Comment: Ok, if that can't be done, how can I lower and increase the brightness?

Comment: You could poke around in the source of Magic Monitor - http://code.google.com/p/magicmonitor/

Comment: Where can I download the source that isn't http?

Comment: Probably in the Source tab via the Subversion checkout url?